# PHP: A different random string is generated every time I use the same variable

Tags: php, string, random

I'm trying to generate a random string and insert it into a database showing the user that same random string. However, every time I use that variable that contains the random string, its value is changed to a new random string. As a result, the user sees a different random string than the one inserted into the database.

This is at the top of my PHP code:

```
$token = GenerateRandomString();
```

This happens when the user submits a form:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (token) VALUES ('{$token}')";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

This is how I show the user the random string generated:

```
<input type="hidden" name="mytoken" id="mytoken" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
```

This is the function used to generate the random string:

```
function GenerateRandomString($length = 5){
$characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charactersLength = strlen($characters);
$randomString = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
}
return $randomString;
}
```

Comment: Do you first show the string to the user and then let him submit the form? Or what code do you use to display the string to the user?

Comment: are you sure you dont call  `GenerateRandomString` twice? how do you show the user the string?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm doing. I'm echoing $token in an html input value.
I just edited my original post.

Comment: @user2921419 So you generate the string and show that to the user, but then when the user submits the form your code runs again and you generate a new string. So save the string into session and then you can use that one.

Comment: Oh, never though of using a session. I will try this out. Thanks!

Comment: @Dagon no, not at all.

Comment: also as all you store is 'token' 2 users on the site at the same time will creates one each, so how do you match them to a user

Comment: @Dagon it's a simple URL shortener, nothing complex. I don't need to match each token to a user, I just check to make sure that the same token doesn't already exist in the database. I didn't include all the code in my original post so as to make it easier to read.

Comment: im assuming Rizier123 's suggestion solved it

Comment: Ok, so I tried using a session. I started the session at the top of the code, I set $token value to GenerateRandomString() and then used $_SESSION['token'] = $token;. I echoed $_SESSION['token'] instead of $token and added $_SESSION['token'] instead of $token to the database as well. But the result remains the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: if i was writing a url shortner, it would have a form the user would submit the url. next page url and 'token' added to db, show the user the new url . (backend redirect when some one hits the url). I dont see why you ever add the token to a form at all,

Comment: @Dagon I know, but that's my problem! How can I show the user the generated URL (the short one which looks something like website.com/gsAMt <- that's the random token) if a different short URL is added to the database?

Comment: sorry im just not seeing the problem

Comment: Ok, let me explain it a little bit better.
1) The user visits my website. A random string is generated and assigned to $token variable.
2) $token variable is echoed in the html code. Let's say for example that the token value that the user sees is GdIXm.
3) The user submits the form, but the token inserted into the database is different than the one that the user gets. For example LxIwV is inserted into the database.

As a result, the short URL that the user gets doesn't redirect him to the URL he entered because it doesn't exist in the database at all.

Comment: ok a new idea: `$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (token) VALUES ('{$token}')";` < that $token should be either `$_GET['token']` or `$_POST['token']` depending on your form

Comment: Works like a charm! You can add it as an answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the page that the form is submitted to:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO mytable (token) VALUES ('{$token}')";
```

that `$token` should be either `$_GET['token']` or `$_POST['token']` depending on your form. Don't forget to sanitize it before putting it in the data base

Answer (score -3):

I guess you don't use global variable.
The value of variable will be the same as before if you use global variabel.

---

```
$GLOBALS['token'] = $token;
```

or it depend on how the action you use such as session, but i think it's not good idea using session, except u destroy it after use it.

Comment: No, it's only per request the same.

Comment: oh i don't see the update :
<input type="hidden" name="mytoken" id="mytoken" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />